# How to find exact cell having matched string in excel in perl using OLE

Tags: perl, excel, ole

I am trying to find exact string in excel sheet using Find command.
I was successful to find the cell having the string, here the problem is 
i am not able to find cell matching given exact string.

Scenario is explained below:

Scenario:
Excel sheet having below values.

C1(value):  ABCD

D1(value): ABCDEFABCD

Input search string: ABCD

Expected value: 3 (C)

Output: 4 (D)

Below is the code which i was using:

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Variant;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';

$Excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
$Excel->{'Visible'} = 0;        #0 is hidden, 1 is visible
$Excel->{DisplayAlerts}=0;  #0 is hide alerts

# Open File and Worksheet
my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Open ('D:\\all_files.csv'); # open Excel file
$Sheet = $Book->Worksheets(1);

# Find Last Column and Row
$search_string = "ABCD";

my $Row_index = $Sheet->UsedRange->Find({What=>$search_string,
    SearchDirection=>xlPrevious,
    SearchOrder=>xlByRows})->{Row};

$Book->Close();
$Excel->Quit();
```

Please help me out to overcome this difficluty. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the flag `LookAt => xlWhole` , as it matches the whole string.

Also, Why did you decide to use `xlPrevious`?

Last thing - for sanity check - also use `LookIn => xlValues` , becuase you're not looking for formulas.

Comment: Is there any code to find exact occrance of string inside excel ?

Comment: As I suggested, just add the flag `LookAt => xlWhole` in: `$Sheet->UsedRange->Find({What=>$search_string,
    SearchDirection=>xlPrevious,
    SearchOrder=>xlByRows})`